# Highlight (power pole) shadows in Bing basemap

Tags: qgis, symbology

I'm creating power pole features using only the Bing basemap in QGIS. Bing seems to be higher res than the Google map. I'm trying to change the symbology of the layer to help highlight the shadows better, but I haven't been successful. Any specific tips on how to modify the layer would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: What is your area of interest?

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be very dependent on exactly what outcome you are looking for.

For example, I used the following settings:

- Brightness: +75
- Contrast: +100
- Gamma: 2
- Saturation: -50

[image]

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

This looks to me like the shadows (in particular, noting the power pole) are highlighted much better.